# Repair Hole in Concrete Foundation

Tags: concrete, foundation

The previous owner of my house had a sprinkler system installed and had it run off the main water supply in the house instead of a separate meter.  I had a new meter installed, so I do not have to pay sewage on my irrigation water.  Now I have a pipe sticking through my foundation that has been cut off and capped on each end.  It is not needed any more.  If I remove this pipe, what is the best material and process to use to fill the hole in the foundation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's not a huge pipe, hydraulic cement would probably do the trick. Hydraulic cement is designed to expand as it cures and is used for reparing foundation cracks.

Comment: hydraulic cement is the right product to use, by a long run. you can buy it in small quantities as a powder and just mix with water. It is also pretty cheap.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything structural - just something to cap the hole and be an approximate match to the rest of the concrete.

In that case you just needs some "patching" mixture - some ready mix post concrete springs to mind.

I'm assuming that the hole is horizontal - if so then just push enough mixture in to make it water tight and smooth it out to match the current surface. Repeat for the other end if necessary.